# How can I edit a page by clicking a button on the another html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example, I have a home page with 2 buttons "show login popup" and "show register popup", and it can popup 2 windows on the homepage. Those 2 popup are divs in the homepage. I keep those 3 html separate, because I want the login and register can shows on any pages as a popup box.

Here is my problem: I have a same "show register popup" button in the login popup page, too. I want to do that, when I click the button, it can hide the login popup (the div in the home page) and "show register popup" on the home page. What should I do?

Here is my code example:

Home Page

```
 <!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home page</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="testjs.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <button id="login" onclick="goto_login()">goto login</button>
    <button id="register" onclick="goto_register()">goto register</button>
    <div id="loginPopup" style ="background-color:red; display:none;">
        <object id="login_location" type="text/html" data="login.html"
            style="width:100%; height:50%;">
        </object>
    </div>

    <div id="registerPopup" style="background-color: yellow; display:none;">
         <object id="login_location" type="text/html" data="regi.html"
            style="width:100%; height:50%;">
        </object>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Login Popup

```
<html>
<head><script src="testjs.js"></script></head>
<body>

    <input id="id" type="text">
    <input id="pw" type="text">

    <input id="login" type="button" value="login">

    <input id="goto_register" onclick="goto_register()" type="button" value="goto-register">
</body>
</html>
```

Register Popup

```
<html>
<head><script src="testjs.js"></script></head>
<body>

    <input id="id" type="text">
    <input id="pw" type="text">


    <input id="register" onclick="goto_register()" type="button" value="register">
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function goto_login() {
var loginPopup  =  document.getElementById("loginPopup");
var registerPopup = document.getElementById("registerPopup");

loginPopup.style.display="block";
registerPopup.style.display="none";
}

function goto_register() {
var loginPopup  = document.getElementById("loginPopup");
var registerPopup = document.getElementById("registerPopup");

loginPopup.style.display="none";
registerPopup.style.display="block";
}

function close_pop() {
var loginPopup  = document.getElementById("loginPopup");
var registerPopup = document.getElementById("registerPopup");

loginPopup.style.display="none";
registerPopup.style.display="none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I set the height to a `px` value, and removed the `<object>` tag for simplicity.  My guess is there is something wrong with your object tag, I have not used it to import html the way you are trying to.

```js
function goto_login() {
  var loginPopup = document.getElementById("loginPopup");
  var registerPopup = document.getElementById("registerPopup");

  loginPopup.style.display = "block";
  registerPopup.style.display = "none";
}

function goto_register() {
  var loginPopup = document.getElementById("loginPopup");
  var registerPopup = document.getElementById("registerPopup");

  loginPopup.style.display = "none";
  registerPopup.style.display = "block";
}

function close_pop() {
  var loginPopup = document.getElementById("loginPopup");
  var registerPopup = document.getElementById("registerPopup");

  loginPopup.style.display = "none";
  registerPopup.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<button id="login" onclick="goto_login()">goto login</button>
<button id="register" onclick="goto_register()">goto register</button>
<div id="loginPopup" style="background-color:red; display:none;width:100%; height:300px;">
  <input id="id" type="text">
  <input id="pw" type="text">

  <input id="login" type="button" value="login">

  <input id="goto_register" onclick="goto_register()" type="button" value="goto-register">
</div>
<div id="registerPopup" style="background-color: yellow; display:none;width:100%; height:300px;">
  <input id="id" type="text">
  <input id="pw" type="text">


  <input id="register" onclick="goto_register()" type="button" value="register">
</div>
```

Comment: I think you miss understand, I want a javascript function that can edit  this page from another page, for example, I have 3 html pages, PAGE A, LOGIN POPUP, REGISTER POPUP. Both POPUP can shows on PAGE A, but I have a button on LOGIN POPUP called "go to register", that can close current popup box and open REGISTER POPUP on Page A. Hope you understand what I'm saying. sry i'm not good at explanation.